# Importing .CSV files HDFS in regular interval

Tags: csv, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have multiple csv files with details of people. I copy this into HDFS using the -copyFromLocal command and I view it using Hive table. But now my new use case is that these csv files in my local gets updated daily I want these data to be updated in HDFS just like the way Sqoop Inceremental import works which copies data from RDBMS to HDFS. Is there any way to do it and suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Does every CSV have the same schema layout? Will that ever change?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every file contains the same fields.

Create a single top level HDFS directory, put date partitions for every day

```
/daily_import 
    /day=20180704
        /file.csv
   /day=20180705
       /file.csv
```

Then define a table over it

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE daily_csv (
... 
) PARTITIONED BY (`day` STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXT -- Use  CsvSerde instead!
LOCATION '/daily_import'
;
```

Then every day after you copy files into the appropriate HDFS location, execute a metastore refresh for new partitions

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE daily_csv;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will let you know if that works.

Comment: Just wanted to ask one thing. What if a same .csv files get updated regularly. I mean suppose I have 2 .csv files. One contains people details and another contains their relative details. So one is called people.csv and another is called relative.csv. Everyday these two files get updated. Today I copy these 2 files into HDFS. Tomorrow will I be able to do an update on the same file residing in HDFS  just like how we do Sqoop Incremental import?

Comment: I have never used incremental sqoop, so I don't know how to do what you are asking, but the files should contain the entire dataset, not only the differences, and you would query them by using the `day` field to get data for that day.

Comment: I mean to say that if my .csv file gets updated then will that same reflect in HDFS?

For example people.csv yesterday has:
1,ABC,Kolkata
2,XYZ,Delhi

Today the same file will have:
1,ABC,Kolkata
2,XYZ,Delhi
3,PRQ,Mumbai
4,MNO,Bangalore

Will a same file named people.csv in HDFS today get updated or I will have to keep multiple csv for a same csv whenever it increases is my question.

Comment: You're welcome to overwrite the files completely, or you can use the layout mentioned in the my answer. If you overwrite, you won't get duplicates. If you use my format, you'd need to do some windowing queries in hive to get unique data (such as the max day for a given person, would result in the most recent record for them)